# Let $X_t = \int_0^t \sin(1 + 3W_s) dW_s$. (1) Find an expression for $X_t$, using Ito's formula. (2) Find mean and variance for $X_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, variance

I have solved above question but I am not confident. I need guidnace if there is a mistake and how do I fix it.

To find an expression for $X_t$ using Itô's formula, we need to express $X_t$ as a function of a stochastic process. Let's define a function $F(t, W_t)$ such that $X_t$ can be derived from it using Itô's formula.

Given:
$X_t = \int_0^t \sin(1 + 3W_s) dW_s$.

We define $F(t, W_t)$ such that $dF(t, W_t)$ corresponds to the integrand of $X_t$. A suitable choice for $F$ is a function whose derivative with respect to $W_t$ is $\sin(1 + 3W_t)$.

Let's consider $F(t, W_t) = -\frac{1}{3} \cos(1 + 3W_t)$. Then, applying Itô's formula:

$$
dF(t, W_t) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial F}{\partial W_t} dW_t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial W_t^2} (dW_t)^2.
$$

Calculating the derivatives:

- $\frac{\partial F}{\partial W_t} = \sin(1 + 3W_t)$,
- $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial W_t^2} = 3 \cos(1 + 3W_t)$,
- $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = 0$ (since $F$ does not explicitly depend on $t$).

Substituting these into Itô's formula:

$$
dF(t, W_t) = \sin(1 + 3W_t) dW_t + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 3 \cos(1 + 3W_t) dt.
$$

Integrating both sides from 0 to $t$:

$$
F(t, W_t) - F(0, W_0) = \int_0^t \sin(1 + 3W_s) dW_s + \frac{3}{2} \int_0^t \cos(1 + 3W_s) ds.
$$

Since $F(0, W_0) = -\frac{1}{3} \cos(1)$, we have:

$$
X_t = F(t, W_t) + \frac{1}{3} \cos(1) - \frac{3}{2} \int_0^t \cos(1 + 3W_s) ds.
$$

This is the expression for $X_t$ using Itô's formula.

For the mean and variance:

1. **Mean of $X_t$**:

   - $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \mathbb{E}[F(t, W_t)] + \frac{1}{3} \cos(1) - \frac{3}{2} \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \cos(1 + 3W_s) ds\right]$.
   - Since the expectation of an Itô integral is 0, $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \frac{1}{3} \cos(1)$.
2. **Variance of $X_t$**:

   - Using Itô isometry, $\text{Var}(X_t) = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \sin^2(1 + 3W_s) ds\right]$.

Comment: First part is correct, my one advice would be on notation: you should avoid writing $\frac{\partial F}{\partial W_t}$ and instead something like $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} (t,W_t)$ is much clearer (where earlier you would have defined $F(t,x) = \ldots$. For the expectation, you say that an Ito integral has expectation $0$ but then go on to give a non zero expectation? There is nothing to do here, an Ito integral (such as $X_t$) has expectation $0$. The error here comes from the fact that $\int_0^t \cos(1+3W_s)ds$ is not an Ito integral but a Lebesgue one.

Comment: Finally, for the variance you can use Fubini's theorem and you're left with $\int_0^t \mathbb{E}[\sin^2(1+3W_s)] ds$ which can be computed explicitly. For instance you can start by "linearizing" $\sin^2$ and then you get an expression with just $\cos(Z)$ and $\sin(Z)$ (where $Z$ is a normal RV), both of which you should be able to compute the expectation.